# What is the difference between SRT and RTP?

Tags: streaming, rtp

I am trying to understand the benefits of SRT over other protocols like RTP. Haivision has a [decent introductory explanation for SRT](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/why-srt-was-created.md) as well as a white paper, but I am unclear how it compares to RTP. There is even a [github issue](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/issues/136) about using RTP with SRT. Don't RTP and SRT address the same problem? Why would you use one over the other (or both together)?
I found a [white paper discussing RTP vs MPEG-TS](http://pdf.textfiles.com/manuals/STARINMANUALS/Envivio/Manual/White%20Paper%20-%20IP%20Streaming%20of%20MPEG-4%20-%20Native%20RTP%20vs%20MPEG-2%20Transport%20Stream.pdf), it'd be helpful if there were a similar comparison made with SRT.